# Angular Pass on Message with Set

Tags: angular

In my Parent Component, I have a Set

```
mySet = new Set();
```

Where I am filling Data in

```
isChecked(e) {
if(this.mySet.has(e)) {
  console.log("item in set");
  this.mySet.delete(e); 
} else {
  this.mySet.add(e);
}
```

And now I want to pass on the Value of this Set via Message to the Child Component.

Template of Parent:

```
  <app-seating-order [childMessage]="mySet"></app-seating-order>
```

Template of Child:

```
 template: `{{childMessage}}`
```

I tried it with a String (not with the Set), which is working by

```
  @Input() childMessage: string;
```

But when i try
  `@Input() childMessage = Set();` it is not working.

How can I get this working?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `@Input() childMessage: Set` instead of `@Input() childMessage = Set()`. You have not set the type of your input.

Comment: Thanks, the programm doesn't know Set. (red underline)And now nothing is working any more :D

Comment: You need also to change your `libs` in the tsconfig.json

Comment: What would I need to change there?   `    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]`

Comment: Try to add es2015